# Neo4j Converting Boolean to an Int

Tags: neo4j

I want to return the count of the union statement, but I'm having a little trouble with my return statement.
Given a venn diagram, the union is the sum of the "areas" of the two circles minus the intersection between them. I'm trying to emulate this, but I ran into a little trouble because Booleans don't convert into ints.

I'm trying to return something like this:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT a.name) + COUNT(DISTINCT b.name) - (a.name == b.name)
```

Comment: Can you give us more of your query? I think you may have some other problems doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `CASE WHEN a.name = b.name THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` (and do sum on that, or something). However, you might have dups if you're doing distinct of the other two--maybe you need to adjust something in the rest of your query to avoid duplicates, if you can give us more detail.

Comment: Yea I am getting duplicates, but I can't seem to figure out how to remove them. You can imagine the query as basically multiple teachers and you have the find the union count of the students per pairs of teachers. Any tips to remove them?

Comment: It would probably be easier if I didn't need to imagine, but I'll try. :P

Comment: Can you change the query to match on two rels, if teachers are connected to students? `MATCH (a:Teacher)-->(s:Student)<--(b:Teacher)`

Answer (score 1):

If we assume your original query looked like the first UNION example in the [neo4j 2.1.5 cheat sheet](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.5/cypher-refcard/):

```
MATCH (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
RETURN b.name
UNION
MATCH (a)-[:LOVES]->(b)
RETURN b.name
```

Then you can get the count of the number of distinct names in the UNION this way:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT b.name) AS n1
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:LOVES]->(d)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT d.name) AS n2, n1
RETURN LENGTH(filter(x IN n2 WHERE NOT (x IN n1))) + LENGTH(n1)
```

I don't see a way to use an actual UNION statement to calculate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit more cypher than you planned to write but I was recently in a similar situation and I ended up putting the sets and intersection in collections and figuring out the resulting difference.

I am sure there is a better way but this is what i came up with.  Essentially, I found set 1 and set 2 and put them each in a collection. Then I found the intersection by finding all of the things that were the same and put them in another collection called the intersection. then I just filtered down each of set1, and set2 against the intersection. In the end I am left with two sets that contain the nodes out of the intersection.

```
match (things_in_set_1)
where <things in set 1 criteria>
with collect(things_in_set_1.name) as set1
match (things_in_set_2)
where <things in set 2 criteria>
with collect(things_in_set_2.name) as set2, set1
optional match (things_in_set_1),(things_in_set_2)
where things_in_set_1.name = things_in_set_2.name 
with collect(things_in_set_1.name) as intersection, set1, set2
with filter( id IN set1 WHERE not(id in(intersection)) ) as set_unique_nodes1, set2, intersection
with filter( id IN set2 WHERE not(id in(intersection)) ) as set_unique_nodes2, set_unique_nodes1
return length(set_unique_nodes2) + length(set_unique_nodes1)
```